# How to update multiple columns of a data frame to existing oracle table using pandas

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, oracle

I want to update all the values in my data frame df1 to an existing oracle table where df1 have the same number of columns and column names as in the table.
I have found so many similar questions on SO but none of them solved my problem.

**Below is my existing table data:**

```
COUNTRY             CAPITAL           TEMP
US                   Wash              20
UNITED KINGDOM       Lon               25
IND                  Delhi             35
RUS                  Mosc              30
BRAZ                 Bras              28
```

**Below is the df1 which needs to be updated to table:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Country":['USA','UK','India','Russia','Brazil'],
    "Capital":['Washington','London','New Delhi', 'Moscow', 'Brasilia'],
    "Temp":[35,30,40,35,38]
    
})
```

**What i have tried so far is:**

```
data_to_update = [tuple(x) for x in df1[['Country', 'Capital','Temp']].values]

cursor = connection.cursor()

update_query="""UPDATE table1 SET Country = :Country Capital = :Capital Temp = :Temp where Country IN ('US', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'IND', 'RUS', 'BRAZ') """

cursor.executemany(update_query, data_to_update)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

**When i try this im getting the below error which i couldn't able to figure out:**

```
cursor2.executemany(update_query, data_to_update)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know tool(s) you use, but - UPDATE seems to be invalid. Columns should be separated by a comma, e.g. `update table1 set country = :country, capital = :capital, temp = :temp where ...`

Comment: @Littlefoot seems to be a good correction, let me try right away!

Comment: @Littlefoot, agree, update statement missing commas between variables

Comment: @Littlefoot commas was the issue! but i have a new error now cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: As I said, I don't know tool(s) you use; all I can say is that all substitution variables must have a substituted value before the SQL statement is executed. I have no idea how to do that; hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Found the issue, i was miss named a column. Much thanks @Littlefoot

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it.